# does wl support n point correlation functions?

Tags: correlation

Is there the facility within WL to support n point correlation functions?
If yes, where? & are there any examples of its use?
(PS I have found a question from 2March2017 regarding 2point correlation function of Ising data, but am looking for more).

Comment: I think you must be significantly more specific in order to pose a question which can be answered usefully. As a correlation function may be expressed as an integral, one could simply answer "Yes" to your question as there is Integrate, NIntegrate and other relevant functions. What do you mean with "support"? Please include also the link to the question you mentioned.

Comment: I have since discovered Malmir et al. Higher-order correlation functions in disordered media: Computational algorithms and application to two-phase heterogeneous material. Physical Review E 98, 063317 (2018). They describe an algorithm for computing 3rd order correlation functions, which appears to be worth pursuing. They discussion 3point probability and cluster functions and 3point surface correlation functions. The relationship between microstructure and macroscopic properties is my area of interest.